# Eloquent models - basing a model on a query instead of a table?

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I am constructing an application in Laravel, making use of the Eloquent ORM for accessing local data.

Part of the functionality of this application involves running complex queries on a remote database. There are a handful of fixed queries that need to be run. Can I create the Eloquent ORM to access the query data like a local table-based model?

By this, I mean I would like to treat the queries like tables in the ORM models, just for convenience, while within the model, the queries are being run on the remote database to fetch the data. These will be read-only models.

Or would I be best (from an effort POV) just running an eloquent SQL query and fetching the data directly, rather than trying to wrap it up into more abstract models? I just don't know how much my approach would be fighting against what eloquent is technically designed to do.

Edit: I would rather not create views on the remote database to wrap up the queries, though it would seem like a bright idea at first glance.

Comment: how do you access the remote database?

Comment: Laravel allows multiple database drivers and authentication details to be set up. An eloquent model can be told to use a specific database in that list.

Comment: In essence it is just "a database", so nothing special about the remote database compared to the local database, except that I can't start creating objects on the remote database - treat it as read-only.

Comment: Ok thanks Jason, I was just making sure that's what you were doing. Of course you can just use Eloquent, the models can have scoped methods that run specific queries (take a look at the Eloquent docs for that). If security is your main goal have you looked into stored procedures on the remote?

Comment: Reading up on contexts, would I do something like this: create a single model that references the remote data base, then create contexts for each query? For example `MyRemote::query1()->get()` and `MyRemote::query2()->where('timestamp', '<', 'now()')->take(5)`? The context functions (query1 and query2) would build up the base queries, though I suspect I would need to override the likes of `where()` so that the conditions could be aimed at the correct parts of the complex query.

Comment: You're getting there. Use the `scope` functions to make the queries more granular as well.

Comment: @Jason what are those queries that you need to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I just built queries against the remote database using the query builder. That gave me the remote data to play with rather than Eloquent models. It served its purpose, but it something I suspect I may want to revisit in the future.

In the end, it is about creating the right amount of abstraction in each layer of the application, without over-complicating things.

Comment: Yes, but how about creating a model based on a table + condition ? Example : i have a table posts and I want a model named CommentedPosts , so it would still point to table posts, but has a condition of only selecting the ones with comments . Hence doing ``` CommentedPosts::all() ``` would discard the posts without comments

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar dilemma  to yours as I want to build a search interface for my app. I decided creating the DB view using a migration class to make my deployment simple. My rationale for setting the Model to the view is to avoid a cluster of relationships.    I'm assuming the view will only transfer data I actually need and make my Model more efficient.

To ensure that the Model remained read only I followed this example https://gist.github.com/scrubmx/d21b58e6222e515a3bf7